# Where can I find a camera for a photographer with a severe acquired disability?

Tags: children, disability

I need advice regarding cameras very easy to use and possibly impact resistant.
A friend of mine, who is a very enthusiastic photographer because of an accident now has a severe disability. He can not use his right hand, and he has difficulty, more generally, in doing complex movement with the left one. I would like to buy a new camera for him that would be very easy to use. For instance, I'd like a camera with very few buttons and a larger "screen". Do anyone know if such a camera exists for disabled users or even for children? Do you have any advice on where to search for cameras with support for disabled people?

Comment: Without knowing what problems exactly your friend has (I do not mean the name of the condition; I mean what is difficult for them to what extent), this is not really answerable in a way that will help them. There are some different concepts of camera controls, though, so you may want to have a look into all of them with your friend, as they will know best what would work and what would not work. E.g. most cameras with a touchscreen offer the option to use it as a shutter release.

Comment: @flolilolilo  i would need a camera without a touchscreen (because it needs too precise movements with a finger) and thus with only few and possible big buttons. I think also that a big screen would be better in helping to take the picture. these are just examples, sincerely I don't really have clear ideas, I'm just looking for some advice by people who knows cameras better than me and maybe have some suggestions in this regard.

Comment: To me the obvious answer to "*a camera with very few buttons and a larger screen*" would be an Android tablet, although obviously it has photographic limitations. So it would be useful to have more specific requirements: for example, is your friend more interested in landscapes, street photography, wildlife, sports, ...?

Comment: Maybe a design that doesn't come with as few buttons, but one that offers a lot of *programmable* buttons, would be best - allowing complex operation with as little complex interaction as possible. About impact resistance: Maybe use a camera cage like the ones videographers use?

Comment: All iPhones can release the shutter by pressing either of the volume buttons. I find this makes holding the phone and tripping the shutter easier one handed.

Comment: @EricShain it could be also a solution. I have to check his ability with. thank you

Comment: @PeterTaylor for me its now difficult to answer this kind of question because his interests of "before" (portraits, documentary, events, but also landscape) are now challenged by its new condition. For now he can move around the hospital and nearby.

Answer (score 3):

The place to start would probably be with [organisations](https://www.makoa.org/org.htm) that [support individuals with severe disabilities](https://www.disabled-world.com/disability/foundations/us-organizations.php).

Those type of organisations are very familiar with the unique needs of individuals suffering from various conditions or injuries. They keep abreast of what products might be available to help such people perform tasks that are difficult due to various conditions.

Comment: Good idea I could start from one of this organisations. Probably I should also search for organisations of disabled photographers or similar. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Great initiative! I've found some links that may be useful:
https://www.atandme.com/?p=474
https://www.photo.net/discuss/threads/which-camera-for-disabled-person-with-only-a-left-hand.299458/